# button behaving weird in react, it's displayed above an element with higher z-index

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

[image]

Hi, I stumbled across this issue and I don't understand why it's happening. So as you can see in the image attached, a button element with default z-index is seen above an element with a higher z-index. The button is only seen like this when it receives a color.

The nav element here has an z-index of 50

```
import LargeNavWidget from './large-nav-components/widget'

export default function NavbarLeftLarge({ navState, setNavState}) {
    return (
        <div className={`${navState ? "block" : "hidden"}`}>
            <div className={` bg-slate-400 w-28 h-screen absolute top-0 left-0 z-20 `}>
                <div className=" w-5/6 h-[385px] mt-16 mx-auto">
                        <LargeNavWidget name='Home'/>
                        <LargeNavWidget name='Invoices'/>
                        <LargeNavWidget name='Quotations'/>
                        <LargeNavWidget name='Clients'/>
                        <LargeNavWidget name='Emails'/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className='absolute top-0 right-0 bg-black bg-opacity-70 w-[calc(100vw-7rem)] h-screen z-50' onClick={() => setNavState(false)}></div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

this is the button element. Same bug happens if I write the code for the button directly in the page that contains them.

```
export default function MediumButton({value, style}) {
    return(
        <button className={`${style} px-8 py-2 rounded-sm border-[1px] border-black drop-shadow-md shadow-black`}>
            {value}
        </button>
    )
}
```

I can't figure out why it's happening. I tried giving it a specific lower index but it completely ignores that.

Comment: It seems like the `<button>` element is higher in the stacking context that is shared with the stacking context parent element of the `z-50` element. `z-index` coordinates are not "absolute", but rather relative to the element's stacking context. Read more about the [concept of stacking context on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context). Also consider providing the full layout if you can't quite work out the stacking context interactions and we could look at assisting further.